React Suspense + ssr : making the server-side error silent
When trying to use a Suspense component on the server side, React throws an error:

Uncaught Error: The server did not finish this Suspense boundary: The server used "renderToString" which does not support Suspense. If you intended for this Suspense boundary to render the fallback content on the server consider throwing an Error somewhere within the Suspense boundary. If you intended to have the server wait for the suspended component please switch to "renderToPipeableStream" which supports Suspense on the server

I'm in this use case:

If you intended for this Suspense boundary to render the fallback content on the server consider throwing an Error somewhere within the Suspense boundary.

because I want the browser to pick up from the loading state, load the bundle and render once loaded.
I followed the recommendation this way:
const LoadableHome = loadable(() => import("./Home.tsx"))

// App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="">
        <LoadableHome />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}

The loadable function is an attempt at adapting loadable-components for the Vite bundler. It behaves differently on browser and server:
// Browser side
function loadable(loader) {
  const LazyComponent = React.lazy(loader)

  const FallbackComponent = (props) => (
    <Suspense fallback={<Pending />}>
      {/* If this ran on the server, the error above would be thrown */}
      <LazyComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  )

  return FallbackComponent
}

// SSR side, dev mode, bundles not available
// we can only render the loading state
function loadable(_loader) {
  const ErrorComponent = () => {
    throw new Error("Server-side Suspense failed as expected.")
  }

  const FallbackComponent = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<Pending />}>
      <ErrorComponent />
    </Suspense>
  )

  return FallbackComponent
}

// todo: server side production mode, using bundle

This works fine but the error gets printed to the console and sent to monitoring tools. How can I avoid that? The error is reported as a server-side rendering error, not through my ErrorBoundary.
Using React 18, React-Dom and vite bundler, not using next.
